# calculate distance between 2 points using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, distance

i have a form that allow user to select from the database the city 's name  fro the first point and then the city's name for the second point then submit the calculate button

the village table contain:

- id
- village_name
- longitude
- lattitude
- district_id

i did this in my code but it does not show anything and the **var_dump** show null

can anyone help me ?????

## map.php

```
    <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['calculate']))
        {
            $pt1 = $_POST['pt1'];
            $pt2 = $_POST['pt2'];

            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT longitude, lattitude FROM village WHERE id = '$pt1' AND id = '$pt2'")or die(mysql_error());
            $num_row = mysql_num_rows($sql);
            if($num_row > 0)
            {
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                {
                    $lon_s = $row['longitude'];
                    $lon_e = $row['longitude'];
                    $lat_s = $row['lattitude'];
                    $lat_e = $row['lattitude'];

                    var_dump($lon_e);
                    var_dump($lon_s);
                    var_dump($lat_e);
                    var_dump($lat_s);

                    $R = 6371; //km
                    $A = pow(sin(($lat_e - $lat_s)/2), 2) + cos($lat_s) * cos($lat_e) * pow(sin(($lon_e - $lon_s)/2) , 2);
                    $C = 2 * atan2(sqrt($A), sqrt(1 - $A));
                    $D = $R * $C;

           echo $D;

                }
            }
        }
```

## HTML code

```
<table width="30%" border="3" align="right">
                <form action="map.php" method="post">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="37%"> Location one: </td>
                    <td width="63%"><select id="location1" name="pt1">
                      <?php echo $opt->Showlocation() ?>
                      </select>
                      <br /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Location two:</td>
                    <td><select id="location2" name="pt2">
                      <option value="0">choose...</option>
                      </select></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Calculate Distance" /></td>
                  </tr>
                </form>
              </table>
```

Comment: lon_e and lon_s are the same. Also, how can id by equal to both: WHERE id = '$pt1' AND id = '$pt2'

Comment: As you've set action to '#', what happens when the `calculate` button, where's the js that actually submits the request?

Comment: mmmm you are right but the problem that i do not know how to do it can you help me ??? i fetch the table and the fields are id name longitude lattitude district_id is their any way to do it ??

Comment: ohh i changued sorry it mmust be map.php

Comment: @user2378026 ok so [here's the script](http://codepad.org/5iLSFX2k) I fixed for you, note that I didn't test it and just wrote it directly from my head.... Hope it helps ...

Answer (score 1):

It's because `WHERE id = '$pt1' AND id = '$pt2'`

you should have 1 on `WHERE clause`

```
WHERE id = '$pt1'
```

Comment: so the query will be **$sql = mysql_query("SELECT longitude, lattitude FROM village WHERE id = '$pt1')or die(mysql_error());**      and how to relate the second **$pt2** ??

Comment: @Newbie i did AS YOU SAID BUT NOW I GET FROM THE VAR DUMP  that the **var_dump($lon_e);
                    var_dump($lon_s);
                    var_dump($lat_e);
                    var_dump($lat_s);**     $lon_e and $lon_s are the same  and the $lat_e $lat_s are the same   how to deal with this error

Comment: @ HamZa DzCyberDeV  what you mean the whole logic code  isn't right??? how to do it in the right way ??

Comment: I'm sorry for replying you so late.. what exactly the error said?

Comment: THE ERROR IS THAT I GET THAT the 2 lat and the long are the same

Comment: guys anyone had find the solution to my error ??? and i appreciate your helps  do i need to add some fields to the table or its just an error in php ??

Comment: @user2378026 I sent you a link in the comments above :p

Comment: @ HamZa DzCyberDeV  how can i up vote for you and thank you  for your big help but still have one question if i want to display the names of the selected values i also put it in an array ????

Comment: @HamZa DzCyberDeV can i show you another query in a different problem that i get it do not have relation with this problem. i had spend 2 days asking and trying  but without any success

Comment: @user2378026 [Check this](http://codepad.org/NlJ5TJw4), hope it helps (also from my head so did not test it :p). If it's a short problem ok, but if it's a long one add me on FB, or send me an email (check my profile). I'm busy for the moment ...

Comment: okkk thank you for your big help i will add you  you are a really a master yet a good person because no one until now had help me as you did tank you

Comment: @user2378026 You're welcome :) You may add what I gave you as an answer and accept it. See ya.

Comment: ok i willl..... the other problem is : **inner join**     **SELECT specialization_name FROM members u 
                         INNER JOIN specialization s 
                                     ON u.specialization=s.specialization_id";

    $result = mysql_query($querySrting)  or die(mysql_error());**  the browser display an syntax error msg

Comment: @HamZa DzCyberDeV i am not able to answer on my own question because i am new